# insertar un valor predeterminado en mysql

Tags: mysql

estoy creando una tabla mysql, pero quiero ademas que en el campo hour se inserte automáticamente la hora en que se hizo el registro  (sin que el usuario tenga que enviarlo desde un imput o algo así) como podía hacer esto?

Gracias por la ayuda

```
CREATE TABLE users (
   user_id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   user varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
   name_last_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   phone_number int NOT NULL,
   direction varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   rol int  
   hour time
);
```

> default 1, pero me da error y para la fecha si no se

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: default 1, pero me da error y para la fecha si no se

Comment: Agrega eso mas el error que obtienes pero en tu pregunta

Comment: El default si me sirve, lo estaba escribiendo mal y por eso me daba error, sin embargo no se como hacer con la hora

Comment: Agrega por favor lo que te menciono a tu pregunta y ahorita te respondo de la fecha

Comment: mysql con que lenguaje estas trabajando para hacer tu app? se puede hacer en automático al momento de ejecución del programa bro.

Comment: Si he entendido bien, lo que quieres es colocar la marca del tiempo en una columna de la tabla, para que esa columna guarde el momento en que la fila fue creada. Si es así, la mejor forma de hacerlo es definiendo una columna parecida a esto: `created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL` así, cuando crees una fila, la columna `created_at` guardará el momento exacto en que la misma fue creada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es posible asignar un valor por defecto para una columna de tipo TIME

Usa DATETIME en su lugar que guarda fecha y hora para conseguir ese comportamiento:

A la columna llamala "created_at" mejor y tendria un valor tal que asi "2020-06-24 21:56:00"

```
CREATE TABLE users (
   user_id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   user varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
   name_last_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   phone_number int NOT NULL,
   direction varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   rol int,  
   created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
);
```

Luego a la hora de extraer la fecha o la hora de la columna, es muy facil:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') DATEONLY, DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%H:%i:%s') TIMEONLY from users;
```

Te devuelve por un lado la fecha y por otra la hora en horas:minutos:segundos

Answer (score 1):

En la declaración de tu tabla, la columna `rol` debe tener esta sintaxis:

```
rol INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
```

Lo cual indica:

- No se admiten valores Nulos
- De forma predeterminada el valor asignado será 1 a menos que el usuario ingrese otra cosa.

Por la parte de la sintaxis de tu `INSERT` debe tener esta forma:

```
INSERT INTO tuTabla (columna1, columna2, rol)
VALUES
(valor1, valor2, DEFAULT),
(valor3, valor4, 2);
```

Lo que le indicamos es que tome el valor por defecto si no le es ingresado nada